# Hibernate SessionFactory method deprecated

Tags: hibernate, deprecated

My hibernate application was working fine but as I upgraded to hibernate 4.4 one of the methods in the following code is now deprecated. Could anyone replace the deprecated method with new method(s), thanks in advance.

```
 Configuration configuration=new Configuration();           configuration=configuration.configure();    
SessionFactory factory=configuration.buildSessionFactory(); //deprecated        
Session session=factory.openSession();      
Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-helpers) gives an example:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your SessionFactory with the following:

```
public static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return factory;
}
```